# After accepting clevertap web push notification confirmation I get browser based prompt confirmation (to allow or block the notifications) very late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, react-redux, clevertap

After accepting clevertap web push notification confirmation I get browser based prompt for confirmation to allow or block the notifications very late.

I want the browser based confirmation prompt (to allow or block the notifications) should come as soon as I accept clevertap web push notification confirmation.
But sometimes it's come instantly and sometime it takes very long time to appear and user leaves the page till then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with skipping the Clevertap dialog, so then it'll show the one from the browser right away. Something like:

```
clevertap.notifications.push({
  "skipDialog":true
});
```